# Add custom animation to collapsible set in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a collapsible set in my jQuery mobile 1.4.0 I want to add a custom animation for this collapsible set when it expands  like  [animation here](https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=help&ctx=keyboard#)

[my collapsible set at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3saa/3/)

I have used the following styles to animate the collapsible but it didn't give me the same result.How can I apply this slide down/up animation  to my collapsible  when its expanded ?

please help me ..

```
.ui-collapsible-content {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.ui-collapsible-content-collapsed {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is my code

```
$("[data-role='collapsible']").collapsible({

    collapse: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).children().next().slideUp(150);
    },
    expand: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).children().next().hide();
        $(this).children().next().slideDown(150);
    }

});
```

This code was tested with jquery mobile 1.4.0.
Thanks.